# What parallelism in my code might cause "Timeout waiting for connection from pool"

Tags: java, multithreading, apache, http, stream

I have this java http client code:

```
 private void init(String[] args) {
        setServerVersion(args);
        commonParallelGenerator.setInputFlavor();
        commonParallelGenerator.setNumberOfThreads("25"); //machine has 31 cores.
    }


...



            Report report = requestsList
                    .parallelStream()
                    .map(request -> freshResultsGenerator.getResponse(request, e2EResultLongBL))

...
```

//uses this http client eventually:

```
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import com.google.common.base.Stopwatch;
import com.google.common.base.Strings;
import com.google.inject.Inject;


public class RoutingUrlHttpClient implements IRoutingUrlHttpClient {

    final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(RoutingUrlHttpClient.class);


    private IRoutingResponseFromStringFetcher routingResponseParser;
    private IRoutingResponseConverter routingResponseConverter;
    private IUrlUtils urlUtils;
    private CloseableHttpClient client;
    private ILogUtils logUtils;


    @Inject
    @Singleton
    public RoutingUrlHttpClient(IRoutingResponseFromStringFetcher routingResponseParser,
                                IRoutingResponseConverter routingResponseConverter, IUrlUtils urlUtils,
                                ILogUtils logUtils) {
        this.routingResponseParser = routingResponseParser;
        this.routingResponseConverter = routingResponseConverter;
        this.urlUtils = urlUtils;
        this.logUtils = logUtils;

        RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
                //time till handshake
                .setConnectTimeout(40 * 1000)
                //happens when you have a pool of connections and they are all busy, not allowing the connection
                // manager to give you one connection to make the request.
                .setConnectionRequestTimeout(40 * 1000)
                //time till response
                .setSocketTimeout(40 * 1000)
                .build();
        client = HttpClientBuilder
                .create()
                .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
                .build();
    }

    private CompleteRoutingResponseDtoWrapper sendRoutingRequestString(int numberOfTriesLeft,
                                                                       String routingRequestUrl) {
        routingRequestUrl = urlUtils.getHttpUrl(routingRequestUrl);

        CompleteRoutingResponseDtoWrapper answer = new CompleteRoutingResponseDtoWrapper();
        CloseableHttpResponse response = null;
        try {

            logger.debug("before sending http");

            Stopwatch stopWatch = Stopwatch.createStarted();
            response = client.execute(new HttpGet(routingRequestUrl));
            stopWatch.stop();
//            String latencyMsg = "after sending http. client-latency: "+stopWatch.elapsed(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) +" server-latency: "+response.getHeaders("Latency")[0].getValue();

            logUtils.addLongToLongStatisticCollector("http.client.latency", (int)stopWatch.elapsed(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
            logUtils.addLongToLongStatisticCollector("http.server.latency", Integer.parseInt(response.getHeaders("Latency")[0].getValue()));

            answer = analyzeStatusCodeAndMsgBody(numberOfTriesLeft, routingRequestUrl, answer, response, stopWatch);


        } catch (Exception e) {
//            e.printStackTrace();
//            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            answer.errorMsg = e.getMessage();
            answer.latency = null;
        }
        handleNullResponse(answer);
        return answer;
    }
```

I often get error:

`Timeout waiting for connection from pool`

when I GET a request from the idea,

but the navigation works well when I navigate throw the browser

Where do you think I should investigate for bottle neck?

Comment: What calls `sendRoutingRequestString()`? Whatever calls it, ultimately HttpClient is failing to clear your HTTP requests quick enough to avoid maxing the pool. Either you're hammering the endpoint, or the endpoint is slow.

Comment: If anything it would be due to a *lack* of parallelism, or not releasing something back to the pool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I haven't closed the httpClient

```
            //try-with-resources
            try (CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder
                    .create()
                    .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
                    .build()){
                response = client.execute(new HttpGet(routingRequestUrl));
            stopWatch.stop();
//            String latencyMsg = "after sending http. client-latency: "+stopWatch.elapsed(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) +" server-latency: "+response.getHeaders("Latency")[0].getValue();

            logUtils.addLongToLongStatisticCollector("http.client.latency", (int)stopWatch.elapsed(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
            logUtils.addLongToLongStatisticCollector("http.server.latency", Integer.parseInt(response.getHeaders("Latency")[0].getValue()));

            answer = analyzeStatusCodeAndMsgBody(numberOfTriesLeft, routingRequestUrl, answer, response, stopWatch);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Closing client will do the trick BUT if you close client after every call you are not reusing connection and not using connection pool.

I would rather make sure that you close HttpResponse which will return connection back to the pool.

```
    try (CloseableHttpResponse response = client2.execute(get))
    {
        response.getStatusLine();
        // ..... read response and such
    }
```

See https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html for more details.

Of course you'd have to be careful with pool configuration as default config sets only 2 connections per route by default (which can be a bit low).